# Android Studio not Working After update 4.0.1

Tags: android

After update to Android Studio 4.0.1, my total Android Studio stop working! The display cannot resolve symbol ‘AppCompatActivity’

[image]

[image]

and when click on AppCompatActivity display

When I click on Setup JDK open Select Project SDK Select any Android API and click the OK button nothing happens. If I click on the Configure button Configure SDK cannot be changed here.
[image]

If I want to open SDK Manager from Tools menu nothing opens. Also, the Settings option can’t be opened from the File menu.
But my previous version Android Studio works properly. But after I've updated all of my projects, the same problem persists. What can I do now? Please help me?

Comment: Try build the project

Comment: Try it. same result.

Comment: What was your previous Android studio version?

Comment: check path to SDK

Comment: check SDK. That is right. Because my previous android studio 4.0 works properly. After the update, this error comes.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. Let me know Is done for 4.0.1?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in my Windows, `lld.exe` command complaining. I've done all that can be done from what I read. It was working in previous 3.6 version prior to upgrading to 4.0.1. I already deleted `this` and `that` ,no re-imports , cache cleanups etc all that you can imagine. The funny thing is that, I have an Ubuntu with Android Studio 4.0.1 and it does not have the problem and was able to build my apk. This has to do with `Windows` probably. I did not remember upgrading from 3.6 to 4.0.1 in Ubuntu as it was just newly installed directly to 4.0.1. Any tips out there?

Answer (score 2):

Somehow `Invalidate caches and restart` did not fix it for me. I had to manually delete everything from `.idea/caches/` folder in the project's root folder. That did the trick.

Comment: This did the trick for me, I don't know why, but the `.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser` file was the cause. I deleted it and things started workign again. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply, wasted hours trying to figure this out before coming across your answer. Removing that file eliminated all errors, pfew

Answer (score 1):

Steps that worked for me:

1. [Windows+R] -> %USERPROFILE%
2. Delete folders `.android` and `.AndroidStudio4.0`
3. Open Android Studio, don't import settings, setup SDK anew (you can target it to where it already resides, so you wouldn't have to download it again), create a new basic project, check if it builds correctly. If it does, then your project will build fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issues while facing issues in some plugin not supported for android studio 4.0.1. Could you please check it and disable the plugin.

I hope it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem , delete file called ".android 4.0" from appdata and reopen android studio without load any configuration and start as new

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but invalidating cache and deleting the `.iml` file and `.idea` directory (watch out for code styles, dictionary, etc) didn't help.

**The problem was solved when I downgraded the Gradle plugin to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'` (from `4.0.1`) and then again set the project SDK as shown in OP's screenshot.**